# Different font sizes used in question titles on "badge details" pages

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

The "badge details" pages are showing lists of posts that awarded the badge in different font sizes:

[image: screenshot]

This is affecting only some of the badges. Others use the same size for all posts on their page, but different size from other pages: for example, [Nice Question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/46/nice-question) shows all posts in the same font size (the larger one from the screenshot) while [Altruist](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/32/altruist) shows all posts in the smaller size.

At @ChrisF suggestion, I checked if questions and answers appeared in different sizes and that seems to be the case: questions are in the larger font and answers are in the smaller.

Browser/OS: Chrome 13.0.782.112 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Are the different sizes for questions and answers?

Comment: @ChrisF Good catch! All questions appear in the larger font size while all answers are in the smaller size.